# Gradle 'Unknown Property' : Importing Plugin within my Custom Plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am writing a custom Plugin that has a task which makes HTTP-API Calls.

Hence within my custom plugin's `build.gradle`, I have included the below `plugins`  tag

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin' version '0.1.1'
}
```

The task within my custom-plugin is this

```
task makeRESTCall() {
    onlyIf {
        !inputList.empty
    }
    doLast {
        //println 'Successfully made REST Call'
        //println inputList

        def http = groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure {
            request.uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
            request.contentType = 'application/json'
            request.uri.path = '/api/v1/validate'
        }

        http.post {
            request.body = inputList.toString()
            response.success {resp, json ->
                println json
                if (!json) {
                    throw new GradleException("Validation Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My custom-plugin gets built property and when i include the custom-plugin in another project and when I execute the task `makeRESTCall`, i get the below exception

> Execution failed for task ':api:makeRESTCall'.
>    **Could not get unknown property 'groovyx'** for task ':api:makeRESTCall' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

the `http-plugin` that I import within my custom-plugin is not getting imported properly in my Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom plugin, you are using [HTTP-Builder-NG](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/) library (`groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder` class), so you need to configure a dependency to this library in your plugin project:

```
dependencies {
    compile "io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.3"
}
```

To make a quick test you could create the following temporary plugin in the `buildSrc` directory of the project you want to apply the plugin to:

**buildSrc/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile "io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.3"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/mycompany/MyPlugin.groovy**

```
package com.mycompany

import org.gradle.api.GradleException
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {

        // ... your plugin login here, with 'inputList' definition

        project.task ('makeRESTCall') {
            onlyIf {
                !inputList.empty
            }
            doLast {
                //println 'Successfully made REST Call'
                println inputList

               def http = groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure{
                    request.uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
                    request.contentType = 'application/json'
                    request.uri.path = '/api/v1/validate'
                }
                http.post {
                    request.body = inputList.toString()
                    response.success {resp, json ->
                        println json
                        if (!json) {
                            throw new GradleException("Validation Failed")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**build.gradle**

```
import com.mycompany.MyPlugin
apply plugin: MyPlugin
```

**Note** : I don't think you need to apply plugin `id "io.github.http-builder-ng.http-plugin" version "0.1.1"`, unless you are using the `HTTPTask` that this plugin exposes, which is just a Gradle Task wrapper around `groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder`

Comment: I included the `dependency compile` stuff that you mentioned here. But still its not getting packed within my plugin and still face the same error. My Plugin is a seperate code base and it gets distributed from `Nexus`. Not within `buildSrc` folder

Comment: it should work. please check the generated `pom.xml` file of your custom plugin:  it should have  a dependency to the library `groupId: org.gradle.sample.http , artifactId: http-builder-ng-core, version: 1.0.3` . If this dependency is there, then it will be automatically added as transitive dependency in the project where you apply your plugin. please provide the content of your plugin `pom.xml`

Comment: No `pom.xml` generated inside my Plugin. I unzipped my plugin jar file and can see just three folders. 1.) my groovy main class `com.mycompany.CustomPlugin.class` 2.) a foldrer named `gradle` which has all the supporting gradle files which was under my `src/main/resources` folder and 3.) `META-INF` folder

Comment: I generate the plugin jar file using `gradlew clean build` command and it generates me a `jar file`

Comment: and how to you include this plugin jar into your consumer projects ?

Comment: Take that `jar` file and place it in `lib` folder.. But am sure there are few more teams who are putting the plugins in nexus by generating a `pom.xml` . am not sure how to do that. so i took the way of generating jar and putting in my project's `lib` folder

Comment: this cannot work , since your plugin has dependencies to 'http-builder-ng-core' lib which is not in your classpath (and this lib may have its own transitive dependencies as well). You really need to publish your plugin into your Nexus, this will create the needed `pom.xml` file, and in your project you will apply this plugin in a standard way (using `buildscript` or `plugins` block): this will automatically resolve the transitive dependencies of your plugin

Comment: you already have needed plugins in your custom plugin project (java-gradle-plugin and maven-publish)  : you need to configure the `publishing` block, and then use the `publish` task.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility for me to have a local repository ?

Comment: yes: a good example is here :  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/plugins/publishing/groovy/build.gradle  . the plugin is pushed to a 'local maven repo', and you can use this same repo in your other project to resolve your plugin.